# VueX: How to commit in a cycle?

Tags: vue.js, google-maps-api-3, vuex, store, commit

So, I am making a component in vueX which gets an array of locations that the user inputs (with the Maps API), and then I'm trying to turn that array into coordinates so I can store them for later usage. To save those coordinates, I am commiting them to the projects store. Everything works fine, except for the fact that only the **last** item of the array gets stored. I think the problem is due to the fact that I am trying to commit many times in a cycle, but I'm not really sure how to fix that. Any ideas? Thank you and sorry if I wrote something wrong, english is not my main language!

P.S. - I can tell that getting the input from the user and pushing it to an array works, and commiting works as well(even if just the last user input), so neither getting the input or the commit itself are the problem!

```
geocodeAddress(geocoder) {
      let markerr = [];
      let address = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < this.pois.length; i++) {
        address = this.pois[i].name;

        geocoder.geocode({ address: address }, (results, status) => {
          if (status === "OK") {
            this.map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            markerr = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: this.map,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

            markerr.setMap(this.map);
            this.coord = markerr;

            this.$store.commit("ADD_ROUTE", {
              id: Number(this.getLastRouteId()) + 1,
              name: address,
              lat: this.coord.getPosition().lat(),
              lng: this.coord.getPosition().lng()
            });
          } else {
            alert(
              "Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status
            );
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your mutation and state.

Comment: @GabrielWillemann thank you for responding, but I figured out the error, which was a stupid condition on the mutation. Thanks to you, I checked the mutation better and figured it out! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!